# top right corner notification HUD window

Tags: macos, cocoa, notifications, osx-lion

When the mac application received a notification from APNS,I want to show a notification HUD window on top right corner of screen.
Many applications have made it,Does anyone know how to do it programly.
I believe there must be a "notification center" or something.

Comment: You might want to accept some more answers, and you have received some pretty good ones on past questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upcoming release of Mountain Lion will have a new API for user notifications.  For Lion, your best bet is to use [Growl](http://www.growl.info).